# Install taiga on local server error

Tags: python, localhost, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install Taiga on my local server via this tutorial (http://taigaio.github.io/taiga-doc/dist/setup-production.html)

**I get stuck at the part where i have to input this code**

```
python manage.py migrate --noinput
python manage.py loaddata initial_user
python manage.py loaddata initial_project_templates
python manage.py loaddata initial_role
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

I get the following **error**

```
Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named 'kombu'
```

I've already google it and there's no way i could find answer to it.

**Please help me out!**

**PIP FREEZE**

```
Django==1.7.6
Jinja2==2.7.2
Markdown==2.4.1
Pillow==2.5.3
Pygments==1.6
Unidecode==0.04.16
amqp==1.4.6
bleach==1.4
celery==3.1.17
diff-match-patch==20121119
django-ipware==0.1.0
django-jinja==1.0.4
django-pgjson==0.2.2
django-picklefield==0.3.1
django-sampledatahelper==0.2.2
django-sites==0.8
django-sr==0.0.4
django-transactional-cleanup==0.1.14
djangorestframework==2.3.13
djmail==0.9
djorm-pgarray==1.0.4
easy-thumbnails==2.1
fn==0.2.13
gunicorn==19.1.1
premailer==2.8.1
psycopg2==2.5.4
pytz==2014.4
raven==5.1.1
redis==2.10.3
requests==2.4.1
six==1.8.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In which command do you exactly get stuck? Can you print here your "pip freeze" command output?

To fix that error you have to install kombu's dependency. Check again everything inside requirements.txt has been fully installed.

This is my "pip freeze" and the commands are working for me:

```
Django==1.7.6
Jinja2==2.7.2
Markdown==2.4.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
Pillow==2.5.3
Pygments==1.6
Unidecode==0.04.16
amqp==1.4.6
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==3.3.0.19
bleach==1.4
celery==3.1.17
cssselect==0.9.1
cssutils==1.0
diff-match-patch==20121119
django-ipware==0.1.0
django-jinja==1.0.4
django-pgjson==0.2.2
django-pglocks==1.0.2
django-picklefield==0.3.1
django-sampledatahelper==0.2.2
django-sites==0.8
django-sr==0.0.4
django-transaction-hooks==0.2
django-transactional-cleanup==0.1.14
djangorestframework==2.3.13
djmail==0.10.0
djorm-pgarray==1.0.4
easy-thumbnails==2.1
enum34==1.0
fn==0.2.13
gunicorn==19.1.1
html5lib==0.999
kombu==3.0.24
lxml==3.4.1
premailer==2.8.1
psycopg2==2.5.4
pytz==2014.4
raven==5.1.1
redis==2.10.3
requests==2.4.1
six==1.8.0
```

Installing kombu fix your problem and with django-pglocks you have to install it referencing to a specific git branch like in the readme has been specified, so you have to run the pip command like this:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Xof/django-pglocks.git@dbb8d7375066859f897604132bd437832d2014ea
```

Comment: hey there. thanks for your reply. i have updated my post with "pip freeze" file. can you please look at it? thank you!

Comment: Nice, I did a quick diff between your pip freeze and mine and there are a lot of differences but the main issue here is you dont have kombu installed. 
alvaro@alvaro:~/Documents/workspace/flu/test$ diff 1.txt 2.txt 
3a4
> MarkupSafe==0.23
7a9,10
> anyjson==0.3.3
> billiard==3.3.0.19
9a13,14
> cssselect==0.9.1
> cssutils==1.0
13a19
> django-pglocks==1.0.2
17a24
> django-transaction-hooks==0.2
20c27
< djmail==0.9
---
> djmail==0.10.0
22a30
> enum34==1.0
24a33,35
> html5lib==0.999
> kombu==3.0.24
> lxml==3.4.1

Comment: So, basically, try this "pip install kombu==3.0.24"

Comment: hey. that kinda solves my problem...but i still have to install others...and when i try to install django-pglocks ...i get the following error ---> "No distributions matching the version for django-pglocks==1.0.2
Storing debug log for failure in /home/user/.pip/pip.log
" ...any clue how to solve it ?

Comment: Hello, if you check the requirements.txt in that case the package is linked to a specific repo branch. You have to run pip like this: pip install git+https://github.com/Xof/django-pglocks.git@dbb8d7375066859f897604132bd437832d2014ea

Comment: I will edit the answer because for some reason in my previous comment doesnt appear the full link

Comment: i still get the same error = "Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-qs5BiR-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-v03EfA-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-qs5BiR-build
Storing debug log for failure in /home/fokz/.pip/pip.log
"

Comment: How did you get that error? Installing django-pglocks with pip from github link?

Comment: You can also try easy_install django-pglocks or pip install django-pglocks (without specifying version= it will install the version 1.0.1 which is almost similar to 1.0.2

Comment: well not yet. i'm trying to install it with this tutorial (http://taigaio.github.io/taiga-doc/dist/setup-development.html). The point is i'm Windows user, and have never used linux before. And we are using taiga, but we only get 2 months of free hosting. So im trying to transfer it to our own server

Comment: When I said using taiga enviorment I mean when you run this command "mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.4 taiga" it will create a taiga enviorment and activate it automatically. If you closed the shell or lost the session your enviorment then deactivates itself. To activate it again you have to run the command "workon taiga" and then try to run pip/easy_install commands with/without github links

Comment: well now i get error "role fokz doesn't exist" ---> fokz = me, linux is driving me crazy

Comment: run this sudo -u postgres createuser fokz

Comment: i think i might have finally got past the errors, though i have no idea how to set it up now and make it work like on windows. thank you for your answers and help!

Comment: You welcome! Maybe you can contact with Taiga's support to get some guidance with porting taiga from Windows https://taiga.io/support/